# gridview.builder is not scrollebel?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

this is my program but it shows error gridview.builder is not scroll so it shows error
in this gridview it is not working properly it shows error [image]

```
GridView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
    ),
    itemCount: 4,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
      return SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child:  Stack(overflow: Overflow.visible,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 200.0,
                width:170.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: kLightGreyColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
                ),
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children:[
                      Text("Name", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: klightFontColor), ),
                      SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
                      Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children:
                          List.generate(5, (index) => Image.asset("assets/images/star.png", height: 20.0,))
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
                      Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "60 \nMin",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                color: klightFontColor,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Column(
                                children:List.generate(6, (index) => Container(
                                  height: 2.0,
                                  width: 2.0,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: kDarkGreyColor,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                                  ),
                                ))
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Hard \nLV1",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                color: klightFontColor,
                              ),
                            )
                          ]),
                    ]),
              ),
              Positioned(
                  top: -190.0,
                  bottom: 0.0,
                  left: 20.0,
                  right: 20.0,
                  child:Container(
                    height: 80,
                    width:80,
                    child:Image.asset("assets/images/food1.png",),
                  )
              ),
            ]),
      );

    }),
```

```
I used the  `singleChildscrollview()`, and `physics: ScrollPhysics(),` but still same error
```

Comment: try use of Expanded(GridView.builder(....)) and you want to scroll horizonal? there's you code said - scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal

Comment: What is your purpose with the code? I don't get it.
`GridView..builder` contains a scrollable view already, and why do you need to`SingleChildScrollView()` inside itemBuilder properties?

Comment: GridView.builder contains srollable view but its not working properly so i added single childScrollview()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the `shrinkWrap` or set it to `false` and delete the `SingleChildScrollView` if you want the `GridView` to take All the space available wrap it in an `Expanded` Widget